# Drag and click on Delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal

I made a simple form in Delphi, it contain a button.

I want to when I click on button, a message was opened. And that button can be move by drag on it.

This is my code

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure Button1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
      Y: Integer);
    procedure Button1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  xx,yy:integer;
  state:integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    showmessage('Clicked');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
    state:=1;
    xx:=x;
    yy:=y;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
    case state of
        1:
            begin
                button1.Left:=button1.Left+x-xx;
                button1.Top:=button1.Top+y-yy;
            end;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
    state:=0;
end;

end.
```

When I click on button, message showed. But when I drag it, it also show "Clicked" message.

Please help me :(

(Sorry about my English)

Comment: This isn't your real code. Why are you showing fake code that doesn't compile?

Comment: I don't want to show all code, I want to know how it works and apply that for my program.

Comment: OK, then I'm going to cast my close vote. You want us to help but you aren't prepared to show code. We don't want to see all of your code. Just a [mcve]. Then we can help.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit my question. I promise I compiled this code.

Comment: I promise that you did not. It does not compile. Please don't ever post fake code. Please don't ever pretend that you compiled it when you did not.

Comment: Screenshot, my code, and it compiled, my program is running.
http://www.upsieutoc.com/image/IvqRqs
What makes you think that is a fake code?

Comment: That screenshot isn't of the code in the original post. Read the question edit history.

Comment: First, I copied part of my code and edited some object names and post. I do not want to show all the code in my app, it's great. I have implemented new full code and compiled. I think new code will help all easy to answer.

Comment: In future, you should learn how to prepare a [mcve] rather than posting fake code.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly I would use an enum for state, but anyway, it is better to use mouseup here, like this (Remove your **Button1Click** procedure)

```
procedure TForm1.Button1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
    if State = '' then // not dragging, so
    begin
       ShowMessage('Clicked');
    end
    else
      State:='';

end;
```

Obviously this is just sample code so ShowMessage would be replaced by something more appropriate.

(as would state!)

### Edit

The other problem that you have is that you are setting drag state too early. You should do it on mouseMove, so a bit like this

```
procedure TForm1.Button1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
    state:=1;
    xx:=x;
    yy:=y;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
    case state of
        1, 2:
            begin
                State := 2;
                button1.Left:=button1.Left+x-xx;
                button1.Top:=button1.Top+y-yy;
            end;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
    if State <> 2 then // have dragged
    begin
       ShowMessage('Clicked');
    end;

    state:=0;
end;
```

Comment: That didn't work. My button can be move, but when I click on it, message didn't show.

Comment: See my edit. The second problem you had was that you were saying MouseDown = drag, wheras in realitiy MouseDown might be part of Click, and it is MouseMove that really performs the drag.

Comment: Sorry - made a couple of minor corrections to edit. Please retry.

Answer (score 0):

I have outsourced the desired behavior to a general service. It can be used for all descendants of `TControl`.

The Code is based on **Delphi XE2**.

**First - The Service:**

```
unit VCLServices;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls;

type

  IDragClickService = interface(IInterface)
    procedure attachClick(Event: TNotifyEvent);
    procedure attachDragStart(Event: TStartDragEvent);
    procedure attachDragOver(Event: TDragOverEvent);
    procedure attachDragDrop(Event: TDragDropEvent);
  end;

  TDragClickService = class(TInterfacedObject, IDragClickService)
  type
    TMyControl = class(TControl); // get access to TControl's protected-visibility
  strict private
    FOwner : TControl;
    FDragging : boolean;
    FLeftMouseDown : boolean;
    FLeftMouseDownPos : TPoint;
    FOnClickCallBack : TNotifyEvent;
  strict private
    procedure onMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure onMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure onMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure resetMouseContext();
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner : TControl);
    // IDragClickService
    procedure attachClick(Event: TNotifyEvent);
    procedure attachDragStart(Event: TStartDragEvent);
    procedure attachDragOver(Event: TDragOverEvent);
    procedure attachDragDrop(Event: TDragDropEvent);
  end;

implementation

{ TDragClickService }

constructor TDragClickService.Create(AOwner : TControl);
begin
  inherited Create();
  self.FOwner := AOwner;
  resetMouseContext();

  // Register Events
  TMyControl(self.FOwner).OnMouseDown := onMouseDown;
  TMyControl(self.FOwner).onMouseMove := onMouseMove;
  TMyControl(self.FOwner).onMouseUp := onMouseUp;
end;

// -------------------------------
// Callbacks
// -------------------------------
procedure TDragClickService.attachClick(Event: TNotifyEvent);
begin
  self.FOnClickCallBack := Event;
end;

procedure TDragClickService.attachDragDrop(Event: TDragDropEvent);
begin
  TMyControl(self.FOwner).OnDragDrop := Event;
end;

procedure TDragClickService.attachDragOver(Event: TDragOverEvent);
begin
  TMyControl(self.FOwner).OnDragOver := Event;
end;

procedure TDragClickService.attachDragStart(Event: TStartDragEvent);
begin
  TMyControl(self.FOwner).OnStartDrag := Event;
end;

// -------------------------------
// Events
// -------------------------------
procedure TDragClickService.onMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  self.FLeftMouseDown := (Button = mbLeft);
  self.FLeftMouseDownPos := Point(X, Y);
end;

procedure TDragClickService.onMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
const
  DRAG_THRESHOLD = 50;
begin

  if not self.FLeftMouseDown then begin
    exit;
  end;

  // The mouse may have been moved while the user clicked (to fast?)...
  if (Abs(X - self.FLeftMouseDownPos.X) > DRAG_THRESHOLD) or
     (Abs(Y - self.FLeftMouseDownPos.Y) > DRAG_THRESHOLD) then begin

    self.FDragging := true;
    self.FOwner.BeginDrag(true);
  end;
end;

procedure TDragClickService.onMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if self.FLeftMouseDown AND (not self.FDragging) AND Assigned(self.FOnClickCallBack) then begin
    self.FOnClickCallBack(sender);
  end;

  resetMouseContext();
end;

procedure TDragClickService.resetMouseContext;
begin
  self.FDragging := false;
  self.FLeftMouseDown := false;
  self.FLeftMouseDownPos := Point(-1, -1);
end;

end.
```

**Second - An simple example:**

```
unit MainForm;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Imaging.jpeg,
  VCLServices;

type
  TFormDragDrop = class(TForm)
    Image: TImage;
    EventConsole: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  strict private
    Service : IDragClickService;
  strict private
    procedure logToEventConsole(text: String);

    procedure onClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure onDragDrop(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure onDragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer; State:
        TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
    procedure onStartDrag(Sender: TObject; var DragObject: TDragObject);
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFormDragDrop.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  self.Service := TDragClickService.Create(self.Image);
  self.Service.attachClick(onClick);
  self.Service.attachDragStart(onStartDrag);
  self.Service.attachDragOver(onDragOver);
  self.Service.attachDragDrop(onDragDrop);
end;

// -------------------------------
// Events/Callbacks
// -------------------------------

procedure TFormDragDrop.onClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  logToEventConsole('Click');
end;

procedure TFormDragDrop.onDragDrop(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  logToEventConsole('Drag Drop');
end;

procedure TFormDragDrop.onDragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer;
  State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  logToEventConsole('Drag Over');
end;

procedure TFormDragDrop.onStartDrag(Sender: TObject;
  var DragObject: TDragObject);
begin
  logToEventConsole('Start Drag');
end;

procedure TFormDragDrop.logToEventConsole(text: String);
begin
  self.EventConsole.Lines.Add(Format('%s: %s', [FormatDateTime('ss:zzz', Now()), text]));
end;

end.
```